# r ggplot2 Ignoring unknown aesthetics with geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do a waterfall plot like the following example:

```
base2 <- data.frame(rot=c("PRini","shk1","PRfim"), value=c(10,5,15),order=c(1,2,3), fim=c(10,15,0), 
                inicio=c(0,10,15), imp=c("net","pos","net"))   
ggplot(base2, aes(fill = imp)) +
geom_rect(aes(x = rot,
              xmin=order - 0.3,
              xmax=order + 0.3, 
              ymin=fim,
              ymax=inicio),
          position="dodge")
```

When i execute that code, i receive the following message:

`Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x`

If i remove the `x` argument, the following message is displayed:

`Error: position_dodge requires the following missing aesthetics: x`

When i remove the `position` argument, the plot is showed up, but without the `x` labels. I want some suggestion to remove the first `warning` keeping the `x` labels.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put all of the aesthetics in your ggplot(aes()), then you won't get a warning. The geom_rect() will get the aes from ggplot() then.

```
    ggplot(base2, aes(fill = imp, x = rot, xmin=order - 0.3,
+                              xmax=order + 0.3, 
+                              ymin=fim,ymax=inicio)) +
+          geom_rect( position="dodge")
```

another solution as dirty workaround:
it seems your plot is fine, but it just gives you the warning. You also could  also use `suppressWarnings()` for ignoring the warning.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mischva11! It was the solution that i was looking for! Like you said, the plot was fine, but i would like to remove the `warning`.